# Play framework 2.6 additional config parameter Dconfig.file work only with activator?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

Play framework dropped support for activator. So I'm trying to use sbt to run play. The problem I'm facing is that providing additional config file parameter

```
run -Dconfig.file='/path/db_.conf'
```

works only with activator.
I have sbt 13.15 installed.
What should I change to make it work?

Comment: Try setting it in the SBT_OPTS variable when starting sbt like `SBT_OPTS="..." sbt`

Comment: I tried to do it like this but this gives me an error SBT_OPTS="config.file='/path/db_.conf'" sbt run

Comment: The notation inside the SBT_OPTS is the same as for jvm parameters (`-Dconfig.file=...`).

Comment: Well, this time this behave like no main config file exists: throws bunch of errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the parameters to sbt.

So for example if you have your config in the conf folder of the app:

`sbt -Dconfig.resource=production.conf`

Or if you want to use a full path:

`sbt -Dconfig.file=/full/path/to/file/production.conf`

(this confirmed working with Play 2.6.0 and sbt 0.13.15)